# Extrapolation numpy curve by asymptotic curve

Tags: python, numpy

I have an numpy array (orange points on the picture below) and interpolated curve (orange line on the picture below). I need to extend this curve by asymptotic curve (green curve on the picture below) to asymptote (dashed curve on the picture below).

I implemented an algorithm that fits curve to my interpolated curve (via finding roots of derivative of interpolated curve and equations of asymptotic curve). But I find it really hard way.

Do you have any ideas how to do it easier?

[image]

Comment: I don't think there is a good answer to this question. Interpolation and extrapolation are two different things and just extending the last element of your interpolation is not exactly meaningful. For a meaningful extrapolation you actually have to have a model to git your data for, meaning that you have to know the functional form of the data. This on the other hand is strongly depending on your specific problem.

Comment: @jotasi, I absolutely agree with you. I did it as you described. But I would like to know maybe there is better way or special function (in numpy or scipy) for doing it.

Comment: I guess I don't really get what you are asking for. Do you want to fit a function's parameter to your data points or do you want to somehow extend your interpolation (which from my point of view does not yield much to any predictive power)?

Comment: @jotasi, Of course fitting a function's parameters would be better, but it seems to be impossible. I have not seen algorithms (excepts optimization) that can approximate points with asymptotic extrapolation. Or rather I have not seen algorithm where I can point an asymptote to correct asymptotic extrapolation. 
I think it is really strongly depending on your specific problem as you mentioned. There is no general approach.

Comment: As @jotasi says you need a model. So if you have no clues as to which family your model should come from, your first and highly non-scientific task is to choose "something simple". You could try low degree polynomials. Of course your case is complicated by the x-axis being logarithmic, so you'd also have to make a choice as to which coordinates to work in (regarding both model and error metric). Once you've settled on a familiy of models there are ML and AIC techniques for model selection.